# jQuery open popup window code does not work on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a simple function which opens up a popup window to show a rendered out preview email.

Works on all browsers except for Safari :(

```
$('#preview_email_btn').unbind('click').bind("click", function() {
    WHOAT.networking.postToServerWithAjax('/invite_preview', null, function (response) {
        var w = window.open("", "popupWindow", "width=640,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
        w.document.write(response);
    });
 });
```

How would this be updated to also support Safari?

Comment: have you tried using other browsers?

Comment: Ah you are right, it also does not work in FireFox :(

Comment: but are you getting to the function or not?

Comment: yeah works on chrome, not on firefox or safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some restriction about popups at safari\chrome [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663861/open-new-window-after-a-click-event-not-working-in-safari-chrome).

I would recommend you to use something like [Jquery Modal UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal), that way you don't have to worry about cross browser issues. Also check browser settings to allow popups.

Comment: Ah ok gonna do this, will render the response on another page and just redirect to that instead of a popup. It's an email preview so a modal over the page will be too big. Thanks