# Upgrading Dropdown Menus

Tags: html, menu

I am a teacher, and I currently run a blog via blogger.com for my class. The link is http://stmlatin2019.blogspot.com

You'll notice that I have some drop-down menus in the left sidebar of the blog. These work beautifully on my laptop and on my desktop. The problem is that my school is now switching to iPads, and I am having trouble getting the menus to work on most iPad browsers. They open in Chrome, but the security restrictions on campus distort the look of the blog on Chrome.

My question is this:  While I know this is not an Apple forum, could anyone show me how to tweak this code so that the dropdown menus work in iPad browsers like Safari? Currently, Safari lets me pull down the menu and make a selection, but then nothing happens once I make a selection.

I guess I should say that I know absolutely nothing about coding. In fact, I stumbled upon that dropdown code on accident a couple of years ago, and, miraculously, I got it to work. Now I'm back to square one.

Here is the code for one of the menus so that you can see what I'm dealing with:

```
<select style="background-color:#eee9dd"
id="Select1" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank');this.options [0].selected=true" class="text_noresize" name="select">

<option selected />Select a link
<option value="" />
<option value="http://www.stmsaints.com/site1.php" /> StM Homepage
<option value="https://mail.stmsaints.com/owa" /> StM E-mail
<option value="http://www.edmodo.com" /> Edmodo
<option value="" /> ____________________</select>"
```

Any help you can offer me would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html)

> The standard window.open() JavaScript method cannot be used to open a new tab and window from a global HTML file or an extension bar. Instead, the global file and extension bars have access to the SafariApplication, SafariBrowserWindow, and SafariBrowserTab classes, whose methods and properties allow you to work with windows and tabs.

Also posted here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664017/3739658)

Safari/Chrome have built-in pop-up blockers that stop this from working. The only Javascript that is allowed to open a new window in Safari/Chrome is Javascript directly attached to click handlers (and other direct user input handlers).

**However, you could display an alert showing pop-up blocked.**

Try this:

```
<select id="retailer" class="windowOpen">
    <option value="#">Select one</option>
    <option value="http://amazon.com">Amazon</option>
    <option value="http://ebay.com">eBay</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('select.windowOpen').change(function () {
    var url = $(this).val();

    var open = window.open(url);
    if (open == null || typeof (open) == 'undefined') alert("Turn off your pop-up blocker!\n\nWe try to open the following url:\n" + url);
});
});
</script>
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/utcB9/1

Comment: I can't get this to work. When I paste the code you provided, I get the drop down menu and then everything else as text. I'm not very polished when it comes to this. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to import Jquery onto your webpage. I posted a demo for you on the post.

Comment: insert this on top of the page beside the other script tags `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Also check I updated the script in my post a little, so do try the latest one

Comment: I know I sound idiotic, but where are the script tags? I am putting this menu in an html/javascript widget in a sidebar on the blog.

Comment: Updated code once again but this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` anywhere and then copy my updated code and paste it between `<script></script>` tags

Comment: Yes, put the `HTML` part before the `script` though

Comment: The updated script being the part that starts with a dollar sign?

Comment: yes put that below the dropdown `HTML` part make sure this line is the same in your dropdown `<select id="retailer" class="windowOpen">`

Comment: It's not working. I have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks for your attempts to help me, though.

Comment: I am trying it on a tester blog so I don't accidentally screw up the real one. stmlatintester.blogspot.com

Comment: Everything is correct except the part that starts with the dollar sign needs to be inside <script>code here</script> tag

Comment: Does the menu code (amazon, etc) even go in the script at all?