# Clicking in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I need to open my app in new window by this link:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://somesite1.com/', '_target', 'width=510,height=413,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes').focus();">Link</a>
```

After opening the application handles events like:

```
$registerSubmitButton.on("click", function() {
var newWindow = window.open("https://somesite2.com", "_blank");
    newWindow.opener.close();
    return false;
});
```

But this click event doesn't work only in Safari.
Why?

Comment: Like this? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target. Then you can fire a function by onClick.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant to your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663861/open-new-window-after-a-click-event-not-working-in-safari-chrome

Comment: I'm not sure, because, it's okay in Chrome and there are not problems with popup window. Window opens, but there are some problems with js-events

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if you cheat a little bit may this will work. I don't have a safari browser so just a try for you.

```
<a id="openWindow" onclick="window.open('http://somesite1.com/', '_target', 'width=510,height=413,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes').focus();">Link</a>

<a id="fakeOpenWindow" style="display: none;" href="https://somesite2.com" target="_blank">

$('#openWindow').click(function(){
     $('#fakeOpenWindow').click();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but in this case the window will be opened by usual link without javascript. I need to open it by my onclick function.

Comment: Does not do the same thing like you want to have? I mean the result are basicly the same as you want/expect, or not? I mean its just a suggestion. Thanks for giving it a try :)

Comment: Not exactly. I need to js-open because I'm using some browser security issues, for example, closing the window. And I need to limit window sizes (in onclick width=510,height=413), and it must be a separate small popup window.