# Open new tab on iOS in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, tabs, onchange

Is there a way to open a new tab on iPad in a Safari web browser using `onchange` event, for example let's say I have a `select` with a few options, and I want to call `myFunc()` when `onchange` event happens.

Let's say `myFunc()` does something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    // do some checks
    // tell browser to open some link in a new tab
}
```

I've tried creating hidden link, setting it's `href` and `target` attributes and using `click()` to simulate user clicking on it, and another one which included `window.open()` and `focus()`, anyhow neither of those worked for Safari (they did for Chrome).

So what's the usual approach to this ?

Comment: Blocked by client agent. You can do nothing. Of course you can unblock popups in your Safari, but cannot expect it to work in general for you site's visitors.

Comment: @marekful well that's just sad.

Comment: check this article http://www.jeffreyvictorino.com/javascript-window-open-on-safari-browser/

Comment: check this also 1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663861/open-new-window-after-a-click-event-not-working-in-safari-chrome 2]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880316/javascript-window-open-in-safari?rq=1

Comment: @bajran tried some of those before, didn't work.

Comment: did u try to disable the popup blocker programmatically

Comment: @bajran No, but I did go to settings and turned off "Block pop ups" feature under Safari when I tested it on colleagues iPhone.